# how to delete one max and one min values from a vector?

Tags: r

I want to delete one max and one min values from a vector.

```
> x<-c( 1,1,1,3,8,9,9)
```

I want to get 1,1,3,8,9  as my result.

```
> y<-c(max(x),min(x))
> y
```

[1] 9 1

> setdiff(x,y)
>      [1] 3 8

`setdiff` can't work . How can i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> x[order(x)][2:(length(x)-1)]
[1] 1 1 3 8 9
```

Comment: why not `sort(x)[...]` ?

Comment: Because it was 2am when I wrote it. :(

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility:

```
x[-c(which.min(x),which.max(x))]
```

(`which.min()` and `which.max()` identify the *first* occurrence of the min or max value respectively)

Answer (score 3):

There's about a bazillion ways....

```
#  Assuming your data is already sorted as in OP,
#  here's a relatively inefficient way to do it...
head(tail(x,-1),-1)
#[1] 1 1 3 8 9
```